# How to catch all exceptions in c# using try and catch?

Tags: c#, exception

I want to write some try and catch that catch any type or exception, is this code is enough (that's the way to do in Java)?

```
try {
code....
}
catch (Exception ex){}
```

Or should it be

```
try {
code....
}
catch {}
```

?

Comment: afaik both work perfectly fine in C#

Comment: You should write code in a way that you know what Exceptions may be thrown and handle each accordingly.  It's bad practise to blanket catch all Exceptions.

Comment: You might want to read my ***Do not catch that exception*** article: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/

Comment: I don't want to handle the exception. I just want my program not to crash if its occur...

Comment: @GordenGram: Then fix the cause of the exception and do NOT ignore the exception.

Comment: C# doesn't get you to declare what exceptions their methods throw, which saves developers from having to write catch blocks or appending throws to their methods which call these methods which I think is a big negative as you can never tall what a method you call might throw back at you. This makes you sometimes write catch() {} blocks as if anything goes wrong you want to back it out etc. when you are calling another persons api you never really know what might get thrown in C# so sometimes useful

Comment: @pengibot The .NET documentation explicitly states what exceptions will be thrown from what method (both on MSDN, and in Visual Studio tooltips). The XML comments allow for you to document what will be thrown from your APIs. If there is even a slight chance an API will throw an exception, I would want the author to document that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's my point, it is not set in stone, it is up to the author to document it. Also it is only comments, I would like to see it more tightly integrated into the actual language. Useful at times, but sometimes can catch you out when you suddenly get an exception and it's because you didn't go into the users online api and read through their "Remarks" to see that an exception could be thrown, e.g. http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/b1d9ff87-214d-d219-af0c-8075512cb3a9.htm this is one that caught me out recently when adding the same file twice

Comment: For those complaining "It's easy to google", this question is the first result on Google now.

Comment: @Oded I have cases where when *any* exception occurs at a given point, I need it to email the team. In these cases, I'll create a new exception with the previous one as an inner exception. Then I'll send the email, and throw the new exception. This way, I have control over what's happening, I can add additional info to the exception, and none of the previous information is lost. Anyone using my functions should know to expect the new exceptions, and not the old ones..

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Both approaches will catch all exceptions. There is no significant difference between your two code examples except that the first will generate a compiler warning because `ex` is declared but not used.

But note that some exceptions are special and will be rethrown automatically.

> `ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

---

As mentioned in the comments, it is usually a *very bad idea* to catch and ignore all exceptions. Usually you want to do one of the following instead:

- Catch and ignore a specific exception that you know is not fatal.

  ```
  catch (SomeSpecificException)
  {
      // Ignore this exception.
  }
  ```
- Catch and log all exceptions.

  ```
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      // Something unexpected went wrong.
      Log(e);
      // Maybe it is also necessary to terminate / restart the application.
  }
  ```
- Catch all exceptions, do some cleanup, then rethrow the exception.

  ```
  catch
  {
      SomeCleanUp();
      throw;
  }
  ```

Note that in the last case the exception is rethrown using `throw;` and not `throw ex;`.

Comment: But unfortunately in release mode this will not catch all exceptions :/

Comment: Muflix can you elaborate on why catch {} won't catch all exceptions in release mode [of?] ?

Comment: worth noting you can call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel the request to abort and not rethrow the exception

Comment: Be careful. Catch all exceptions catch ALL exceptions. Things like the System running out of memory and Rider will warn on this.

Answer (score 9):

Note that besides all other comments there is a small difference, which should be mentioned here for completeness!

With the empty catch clause you can catch non-CLSCompliant Exceptions when the assembly is marked with **"RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = false)"** (which is true by default since CLR2). [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264489.aspx) [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140816175210/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/01/07/non-cls-exceptions.aspx) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531077/will-clr-handle-both-cls-complaint-and-non-cls-complaint-exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

I catch all the exceptions and store it in database, so errors can be corrected easily - the page, place, date etc stored

```
try
{     
   Cart = DB.BuyOnlineCartMasters.Where(c => c.CmpyID == LoginID && c.Active == true).FirstOrDefault();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ErrorReport.StoreError("CartMinifiedPartial-Company", e);  
    -- storing the error for reference
}
```

Storing

```
public static void StoreError(string ErrorPage, Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            eDurar.Models.db_edurarEntities1 DB = new Models.db_edurarEntities1();
            eDurar.Models.ErrorTable Err = new eDurar.Models.ErrorTable();
            Err.ErrorPage = ErrorPage;
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                Err.ErrorDetails = e.Message;
            }
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Err.InnerException = e.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            }

            Err.Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
            DB.ErrorTables.AddObject(Err);
            DB.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Catch global all exceptions in app

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers, try add a few lines explaining what the problem was and how your code fixes it

Comment: I don't get how this should answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but only the first one will allow you to inspect the Exception itself.

Both swallow the Exception, and you should only catch exceptions to do something meaningfull. Hiding a problem is **not** meaningful!

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct.

If you need to do something with the Exception object in the catch block then you should use

```
try {
    // code....
}
catch (Exception ex){}
```

and then use `ex` in the catch block.

Anyway, it is not always a good practice to catch the Exception class, it is a better practice to catch a more specific exception - an exception which you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to catch **ALL EXCEPTIONS** in the application, You can write:

```cs
try
{

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new YourFormName());

}
catch (Exception ex) // This is optional if you want to display the exception
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); // using the "ex" defined in the catch phrase to show the exception in a message box, again, optional if you do not want to show the issue.

}
```

in the `Program.cs` file. This way, every exception in the application will be handled inside the brackets of the catch phrase.

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{

..
..
..

}

catch(Exception ex)
{

..
..
..

}
```

the Exception ex means all the exceptions.